# Geom_histogram x-axis shifted to the right

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I'm plotting a `geom_histogram` and the x-axis does not align with the zero value, it is shifted to the right.

My data looks something like this:

```
Year   Species   Length  Group
2015   GHT       76      1 
2015   GHT       93      0 
2015   SDL       52      0
2015   SDL       37      1
2016   SDL       73      1
2016   SDL       59      0
2016   GHT       49      1
2016   GHT       67      0
```

I plot it using the following code:

```
ggplot(subset(Mydata, Year %in% c("2015") & Species %in% c("SDL")),
       aes(x = Length, fill = Group)) +
scale_fill_manual(values = group_colours) +
theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = 'bold'), axis.text = element_text(size = 20), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 18), legend.position = "none", plot.background = element_rect(fill = alpha("white", "0")))
```

However, when the figure is produced the x axis does not start at 0 but is shifted to the right slightly. I have tried scale_x_continuous(expand = (0,0)) but nothing works and can not find similar problem online.

Any solutions?

[image]

Comment: @JeroenBoeye not a duplicates. This one was the alignement for each bar.

Comment: I have found a solution. Adding boundary to the geom_hist code line:          `geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, fill = "grey", colour= "black", boundary = 0)`